# To order "the works" in a restaurant

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the episode *The Cafe*, Jerry Seinfeld enters a restaurant and says:

> You go back there in that kitchen and tell your chef I want **the works**.

Does it mean that he wants 1) the dishes he ordered *cooked with the excellence*, or 2) just *everything* they can offer today? To support the second choise, I will refer to the *Subway* eateries: when you choose the salad, you can choose "the works", which means a mix of all salads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The works" is also used outside of diners, often meaning giving a task your full attention, really do your best, check and optimise in every way that comes to mind (... I can add similar phrases almost ad infinitum but I think you catch the drift).

Related idioms are *the whole she-bang*, *the whole enchilada*, etc.

Answer (score 5):

In general,  *the works* means all the available toppings for a particular dish.  It comes from diner slang:

> **The works**: a hamburger, hotdog, sandwich or similar with all condiments on it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diner_lingo#

Most of the items on the list I linked to are uncommon, but several have made it into common usage, such as:

> **Sunny-side up:** eggs fried without flipping them, so the yolk looks just like a sun on white background
>
> **Rabbit food:** lettuce
>
> **Pigs in a blanket:** sausages wrapped in pancakes

---

In your specific example of the Seinfeld script:
http://www.seinfeldscripts.com/TheCafe.html

> **Jerry:** Well, congratulations my friend. You know, I sorry I missed the grand re-opening. I was out of town for about a week.
>
> **Babu:** You see how I listened. I worked very hard, borrowed more money.
>
> **Jerry:** I think it's fantastic. Has a certain indefinable charm.
>
> **Babu:** You wish to eat?
>
> **Jerry:** Let me tell you something Babu. You go back there in that kitchen and tell your chef I want *the works.*
>
> **Babu:** Very good.

It appears that Jerry is using *the works* loosely to mean something like   *"make me something fancy and complicated to celebrate your grand-reopening."*  This is not the most common usage - normally you would name a specific menu item and say you want the works on it.

> I'd like a hotdog, with *the works,* please.
>
> I'd like a ham sandwich, and give me *the works.*

Comment: Just to clarify: "the works" means all the toppings or extras available for that menu item. It doesn't mean every item on the menu. If you say "I want a hot dog with the works" you will likely get a hot dog with ketchup, mustard, relish, maybe onions, chili, whatever toppings the restaurant might have. They wouldn't also bring you a chicken sandwich and a bowl of soup, though.

Comment: Pigs in the blanket is pork sausage wrapped in biscuit or kolache dough in my part of the US. It's [difficult to define exactly what is and isn't "pigs in the blanket"](http://iate2012.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/happy-national-pigs-in-a-blanket-day-424/).